# Creating controlled input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie and learning React with FreeCodeCamp. On this challenge it says:

> When you type in the input box, that text is processed by the
> `handleChange()` method, set as the `input` property in the local state,
> and rendered as the value in the input box on the page. The component
> state is the single source of truth regarding the input data.

I wrote this solution:

```
 class ControlledInput extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    input: ''
  };
  // Change code below this line
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  // Change code above this line
}
// Change code below this line
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    input: event.target.value
  })
}
// Change code above this line
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { /* Change code below this line */}
      <input value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange()} />
      { /* Change code above this line */}
      <h4>Controlled Input:</h4>
      <p>{this.state.input}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
};
```

the console says:

> “Build error, open your browser console to learn more.”

Where am I doing wrong? I cannot see my mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is related to how you assign the event handler to `onChange`.

`onChange` expects a callback function which will be fired when value of the input is changed. With `onChange={this.handleChange()}` in your post, you actually assigns `undefined` to `onChange` since `handleChange` function update the component state but it doesn't return anything.

Change it to `onChange={this.handleChange}` does what you expect it to work. When input is changed, `this.handleChange` will be called and `event` object will be passed in as parameter.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: That's not true. It doesn't assign `undefined`, it throws because `event` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `handleChange` instead of passing its reference as the `onChange` prop.

Answer (score 1):

You likely do not need to run your handleChange method in the onChange prop. So you would have this instead:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```